# Unexpected behavior with label transition on active state for input

Tags: html, css, transition

Why is there a gap on the label when it's `left:0` and absolutely positioned?

Trying to recreate the UI similar to Material design.  I have tried using `translateY(-6px)` or whatever, but that isn't dynamic for labels with more characters.

```css
.formField {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 24px) scale(1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input:focus+.label {
  transform: translate(0, 1.5px) scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="formField">
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="name" />
    <label for="name" class="label">Hello</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Open the page in your browser's inspector and check the margin and padding. It may be inheriting a value that is adding margin or padding to the left. You can also change the CSS live in the inspector to see what changes might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the origin of a transform is "50% 50%", which is exactly in the center of any given element.

Try adding `transform-origin: bottom left;` to your `.label`

```css
.formField {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: translate(0, 24px) scale(1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input:focus+.label {
  transform: translate(0, 1.5px) scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="formField">
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="name" />
    <label for="name" class="label">Hello</label>
  </form>
</div>
```